# why my regex not working which is having a `or`

Tags: python, regex

I got the expected when i did `re.findall(r'applepast[ry|e]', s17)` but i am not able understand why i need to give `+` here, because alread explicitly i am giving `e|ry`

```
import re
s17 = 'find word that match applepastry, applepie or applepaste'
re.findall(r'applepast[ry|e]', s17)
```

My Out

```
['applepastr', 'applepaste']
```

My Expected

```
['applepastry', 'applepaste']
```

Comment: That's a character class. Try instead `re.findall(r'applepast(?:ry|e)', s17)`

Comment: Character classes work for a single character, so [rye] matches either r,y or e